# How do advocates of Christian mortalism (aka "Soul sleep") interpret passages that suggest that humans remain conscious after leaving their bodies?

Tags: exegesis, death, afterlife, spirit, christian-mortalism

There are several passages in Scripture that suggest that human beings are still alive/conscious after being separated from their bodies (because of death or due to some sort of out-of-body experience). For instance:

- The Rich Man and Lazarus ([Luke 16:19-31](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+16%3A19-31&version=NASB))
- Saul's conversation with Samuel's spirit through the assistance of a medium/spiritist. ([1 Samuel 28:8-19](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+samuel+28%3A8-19&version=NASB))
- Jesus talking to Moses and Elijah during the transfiguration ([Matthew 17:1-8](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+17%3A1-8&version=NASB))
- [2 Corinthians 12:2-4](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=%282+Corinthians+12%3A2-4&version=NASB)

> 2 I know a man in Christ, who fourteen years ago—whether in the body I do not know, or **out of the body** I do not know, God knows—such a man was caught up to the third heaven. 3 And I know how such a man—whether in the body or **apart from the body** I do not know, God knows— 4 was caught up into Paradise and heard inexpressible words, which a man is not permitted to speak.

- [2 Corinthians 5:8](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2+Corinthians+5%3A8&version=NASB)

> 8 but we are of good courage and prefer rather to be **absent from the body and to be at home with the Lord**.

- [Philippians 1:21-24](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Philippians+1%3A21-24&version=NASB)

> 21 For to me, to live is Christ, and to die is gain. 22 But if I am to live on in the flesh, this will mean fruitful labor for me; and I do not know which to choose. 23 But I am hard-pressed from both directions, **having the desire to depart and be with Christ, for that is very much better; 24 yet to remain on in the flesh** is more necessary for your sakes.

- The apostle John, who claims to be "in the Spirit" multiple times in Revelation:

> 10 I was **in the Spirit** on the Lord’s day, and I heard behind me a loud voice like the sound of a trumpet, ([Revelation 1:10](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=revelation+1%3A10&version=NASB))

> 2 Immediately I was **in the Spirit**; and behold, a throne was standing in heaven, and someone was sitting on the throne. ([Revelation 4:2](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=revelation+4%3A2&version=NASB))

> 3 And he carried me away **in the Spirit** into a wilderness; and I saw a woman sitting on a scarlet beast, full of blasphemous names, having seven heads and ten horns. ([Revelation 17:3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=revelation+17%3A3&version=NASB))

> 10 And he carried me away **in the Spirit** to a great and high mountain, and showed me the holy city, Jerusalem, coming down out of heaven from God, ([Revelation 21:10](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=revelation+21%3A10&version=NASB))

I'm not sure if this list is exhaustive (edits are welcome), but at least these are some of the most notable examples in my opinion. How do [Christian mortalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_mortalism) advocates make sense of these and similar passages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do adherents of soul-sleep interpret the parable of Rich man and Lazarus (Lk 16:19–31)?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/59681/how-do-adherents-of-soul-sleep-interpret-the-parable-of-rich-man-and-lazarus-lk)

Comment: You're asking about too many different passages here - different topics, contexts, and genre mean that each could have a different explanation. The first has already been asked before. Please ask about the others separately.